# Part of the Body of the material-ui Table is not being displayed

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the following code

```
<Table
  fixedHeader={true}
  height={400}
  overflow={'hidden'}>
  <TableHeader displaySelectAll={false} adjustForCheckbox={false}>
    <TableRow>
      <TableHeaderColumn>Date</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn>Production</TableHeaderColumn>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHeader>
  <TableBody displayRowCheckbox={false} showRowHover={true} width={'100%'}>
      <TableRow style={{ width: 100 }}>
      <TableRowColumn></TableRowColumn>
      <TableRowColumn}></TableRowColumn>
    </TableRow>
  </TableBody>
</Table >
```

And it is giving the following result

[image]

I think I need to remove these properties from the table, but I can not access them
[image]

I'm using the version 0.20.0 of material-ui.